# Using grep in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the below code snippet. I need to insert a `grep` command in the appropriate place to find only grades between 80 and 89 and store them in a separate array called `@GradeB`. I've tried using `@GradeB = grep("8[0-9]", @Grades);`, but that puts everything into `@GradeB`. Where am I going wrong to get only grades between 80-89 into `@GradeB`? For full disclosure, this is is homework, but I am allowed to use any and all resources available to me.

```
@Grades = ("Name: Shemp      Grade: 82",
           "Name: Curly      Grade: 62",
           "Name: Curly Joe  Grade: 58",
           "Name: Joe        Grade: 50",
           "Name: Moe        Grade: 88",
           "Name: Larry      Grade: 82");


# grep command here
print join("\n", @GradeB);
```

Comment: Good point, yes, it is, I just updated the main post to say so.

Comment: `"8[0-9]"` is a string that is neither `""` nor `"0"`.  As such it is always TRUE.

Comment: `grep` checks each value of a list. Can you show that you can find the value of the grade from a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` returns each item in a list for which the expression evaluates to true. The expression

```
"8[0-9]"
```

is a string, and it always evaluates to true. You probably meant to use a regular expression instead:

```
my @b_grades = grep /Grade: 8[0-9]$/, @grades;
# Alternately, my @b_grades = grep { /Grade: 8[0-9]$/ } @grades;
```

Note that I've used a more specific regex than just `/8[0-9]/`, which would match things like:

```
Name: Inmate 12789132    Grade: 12
```

---

This approach works, but isn't very flexible. As Borodin points out in the comments, changing the regex to match scores between, say, 79 and 88 is difficult. It would be better to extract the scores so we can do numerical comparisons:

```
my @b_grades = grep {
                        if (/Grade: (\d+)$/)  {
                            $1 if ($1 >= 80 && $1 < 90);
                        }
                    } @grades;
```

This is just a different way of writing [Borodin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22258996/176646).

---

Note that an array is not the best choice of data structure for this. When you have a list of key/value pairs, think "hash." In this case, you can use names as keys and grades as values:

```
my %grades = (
    Shemp       => 82,
    Curly       => 62,
    'Curly Joe' => 58,
    Joe         => 50,
    Moe         => 88,
    Larry       => 82
);
```

Note that quotes are optional around keys that only consist of letters, digits, and underscores. To access the values in the hash, use the aptly-named `values` function:

```
my @grades = values %grades;
```

Using `grep` as before to get all the B's:

```
my @b_grades = grep { $_ >= 80 && $_ < 90 } values %grades;
print join ',', @b_grades;
# 88,82,82
```

This gives us a list of grades, but now we have no idea who they belong to. For that, we need to use `keys`, which, strangely enough, returns a list of all the keys in our hash:

```
my @b_students = grep { $grades{$_} >= 80 && $grades{$_} < 90 } keys %grades;
print "Name: $_\tGrade: $grades{$_}\n" for @b_students;
# Name: Moe       Grade: 88
# Name: Larry     Grade: 82
# Name: Shemp     Grade: 82
```

Comment: Well that kinda spoils the tutorial. It also may not work if there are digits in the name field

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I needed. I didn't realize I needed the `/`s to make it recognize it as regex. Thank you!

Comment: @Vaindil: I'll make sure to sign in as `Joe 90` if you're writing the exam code!

Comment: ***Update!*** There are fewer Grade A passes this year so Grade B has changed to the range 79 to 88. Please can you quickly fix your program?

Comment: @Borodin So sad that grade inflation is a real problem and not just a hypothetical. See my latest edit.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Close, but the requirement was a `grep` of the original `@Grades` array. Don't worry  - I'm stretching the point for the benefit of the OP :)

Comment: @Borodin Updated again. Thank you for the prodding; my initial answer was crap :)

Comment: @Vaindil Please see the updated version of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take look at perldoc for `grep`:

```
   grep BLOCK LIST
   grep EXPR,LIST
```

Grep evaluates `BLOCK` or `EXPR` for every element of `LIST` and returns list composed of elements for which `BLOCK` or `EXPR` evaluate to true value. As you specify *string* `"8[0-9]"`, which is always true, every list element is returned.

You need to pass regular expression as `EXPR`:

```
@GradeB = grep /8[0-9]/, @Grades;
```

Comment: I didn't realize I needed the `/`s to make it recognize that it's regex, which was my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is best not to use capitals for lexical variable names.

This solution works by extracting the string of digits that follow `Grade:` and comparing it with the specified range.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @grades = (
  "Name: Shemp      Grade: 82",
  "Name: Curly      Grade: 62",
  "Name: Curly Joe  Grade: 58",
  "Name: Joe        Grade: 50",
  "Name: Moe        Grade: 88",
  "Name: Larry      Grade: 82",
);

print "$_\n" for grep {
  /grade\s*:\s*(\d+)/i and $1 >= 80 and $1 < 90;
} @grades;
```

**output**

```
Name: Shemp      Grade: 82
Name: Moe        Grade: 88
Name: Larry      Grade: 82
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `map()` and `grep()`. The first one creates an arrayref to keep the whole line and the last number in it, the `grep()` compares them, and last `map()` extracts the whole line of those which matched:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @Grades = ("Name: Shemp      Grade: 82",
           "Name: Curly      Grade: 62",
           "Name: Curly Joe  Grade: 58",
           "Name: Joe        Grade: 50",
           "Name: Moe        Grade: 88",
           "Name: Larry      Grade: 82");


# grep command here

my @GradeB = 
    map { $_->[0] } 
    grep { $_->[1] >= 80 and $_->[1] <= 89 } 
    map { [$_, (split)[-1]] } @Grades;

print join("\n", @GradeB);
```

It yields:

```
Name: Shemp      Grade: 82
Name: Moe        Grade: 88
Name: Larry      Grade: 82
```

Comment: -1 for gross unnecessary complication. This can be very simply done in a  single line if all you are doing to separate the grade is `(split)[-1]`.